# delete duplicate keywords javascript

Tags: javascript, imacros

i scraped a list of 10K Keywords and i want to delete the lines with 2 or more duplicate keywords.

example keywords:

```
abc electronics address
abc electronics sales
abc electronics black friday
electronics ps4
electronics ps3
```

it should look like this:

```
abc electronics address
electronics ps4
electronics ps3
```

I want to do this with javascript but im really not sure how to go about this, can you guys help me figure it out thanks!!! This is what i have im thinking i can somehow use the remove method but thats as far as ive gotten i dont know what to do.

```
var saveKeywords;
saveKeywords =  "CODE:";
saveKeywords +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA ATTR=NAME:comment EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n"; 

var saveKeywords = iimGetLastExtract();
var removeDuplicates = saveKeywords.remove(duplicateKeywords);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to get every line from the list and split the string, get the array, filter it to remove duplicate items, join them back.

```
var uniqueList=string.split(' ').filter(function(item,i,allItems){
    return i==allItems.indexOf(item);
}).join(',');

$('#output').append(uniqueList);
```

For non supporting browsers you can tackle it by adding this in your js.

```
if (!Array.prototype.filter)
{
  Array.prototype.filter = function(fun /*, thisp*/)
  {
    "use strict";

    if (this == null)
      throw new TypeError();

    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun != "function")
      throw new TypeError();

    var res = [];
    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (i in t)
      {
        var val = t[i]; // in case fun mutates this
        if (fun.call(thisp, val, i, t))
          res.push(val);
      }
    }

    return res;
  };
}
```